# Xamarin PCL - How can I upload/download a File to/from a FTP Server?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ftp, portable-class-library

I'm currently developing a mobile app using Xamarin. In the current version only Android is supported, but this will expand to Windows and iOS.

So my question is: How can I make a PCL that allows me to download - cross plattform - a file from a FTP server or upload - cross plattform - a file to a FTP server? Since the FtpWebReuquest class is not avaiable in the PCL - neither the WebRequest class.

Comment: find a PCL package that supports FTP, or use DI to inject FTP support from your platform specific projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject code from platform specific libraries. Why not using MVVM framework like MVVMCross that helps a lot with this? https://github.com/mvvmcross/mvvmcross